# Jquery calculate sub total from fields - qty and price by class and grand Total sum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have prepared this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kY98p/)

The problem is that I have many rows containing product qty * price = sub total
This also must dynamically calculate grand total for all sub total amounts. And the biggest problem is the trigger since we may not have change trigger on the `qty` select fields..  really complicated for me. 
I am so far stacked here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var qty=$('.qty').val();
    var price = $('.price').val();
    var sum = 0;

    $('.amount').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Please give me idea for:

1. Which trigger to use so it can calculate on page load as well and if qty dropdown is changed too.
2. How to calculate each row first

thank you for your help and time in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have your answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/kY98p/10/

I changed the html to use the tags thead and tfoot for header and footer

Its just a cycle over the lines where you get the quantity and price and update the amount...

Here is the function that you should call:

```
function update_amounts()
{
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
        var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var amount = (qty*price)
        sum+=amount;
        $(this).find('.amount').text(''+amount);
    });
    //just update the total to sum  
    $('.total').text(sum);
}
```

And the event that you need is:

```
$('.qty').change(function() {
    update_amounts();
});
```

UPDATE: jsfiddle with total: http://jsfiddle.net/kY98p/11/

Comment: you solution is shortest ! Well done, but it doesnt calculate on page load? or I am wrong?

Comment: Sure it calculates. Just call the update_amounts() in $(document).ready ... Check the jsfiddle ;)

Comment: I commented for you to add because you did not have a field to insert the total... If you want to replace 'TOTAL' by the sum just add: $('.total').text(sum);

Comment: you are the best man.. I accept your answer too and vote for it ! Thank you !":)

Comment: Jose, are you still here

Comment: I have several select dropdowns for ech product, but I did not included them in the fiddle. The problem is that you search for selected value on select and there are more than 1 selects, which are not numbers, so grand total comes NAN, how to search selected value by select dropdown ID..

Comment: Just add a class to each select then use: $(this).find('.class option:selected').val(); I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kY98p/13/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48508/discussion-between-thecore7-and-jose-barbosa)

Comment: To decrease using $(this) .. Best to use $this = $(this) .. as a best practice

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/KXj9N/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var amt = $('.amount:gt(0)'), //select element with class greater than one
        tot = $('#total'); // cache selectors
    function calculator() {
        amt.text(function () { // set text of class amount elements
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr'); // get tr
            var qty = tr.find('.qty').val(); // find it in current tr and get value of element with class qty
            var price = tr.find('.price').val(); //get price 
            return parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price); // return product
        });
        tot.text(function () {  //get total
            var sum = 0; //set sum = 0
            amt.each(function () { //run through all element with class amount
                sum += parseFloat($(this).text()); // add text to sum
            });
            return sum;  //set sum to total
        });
    }
    calculator(); //call the above function
    $('.qty,.price').change(calculator);// run calculator function when element with class qty or price is changed
});
```

Comment: Tushar, thank you first ! Are you sure it is working? I tested and even on change triger doesnt work.. please check this http://jsfiddle.net/kY98p/4/

Comment: @thecore7 yes it is check --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/kY98p/5/  it was not working as added extra text before function `down vote

accept`

Comment: now it is OK ! I accept it ! Thank you very much! Thank you all guys ! Answered..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one (I changed your html template). Solution work as you want:
 1. Calculate each row (find closest input and get data from it)
 2. Calculate total and put to span
 3. If you will add more selected(with my work class) it will be work

```
$(".work").on("change", function(){
      var total = 0;
      $(".work").each(function(){
          var val = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='text']").val();
          total = total + ($(this).val()*val || 0);
      });
      $(".total").text(total);
    });
```

And html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Product name</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th align="center"><span id="amount" class="amount">Amount</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Product 1</td>
       <td>
         <select value="" class="qty work" name="qty">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
         </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" value="11.60" class="price"></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="amount" class="amount">0</span> eur</td></tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Product 2</td><td>
         <select value="" class="qty work" name="qty">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
         </select>
       </td> 
       <td><input type="text" value="15.26" class="price"></td>
       <td align="center"><span id="amount" class="amount">0</span> eur</td></tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2"></td>
       <td align="right"><span id="total" class="total">TOTAL</span> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And [work demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kY98p/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works in with your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kY98p/20/) with one minor DOM update.  I put the header of the table in a THEAD so that you can count on the TBODY TR rows to be those with data.

Here we have functions to compute the total of each row and of the whole table.
When you change a row, we recompute that row and then re compute the total.
When we load the page, we recompute everything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function computeRowTotal(row) {
        var $row = $(row)
        var qty = $row.find('.qty').val();
        var price = $row.find('.price').val();
        if (qty && price) {
            $row.find('.amount').html(qty * price);
        }
    }

    function computeTotal() {
        var total = 0.0
        $('tbody tr .amount').each(function () {
            console.log('T', $(this).text());
            total += parseFloat($(this).text());
        })
        $('tbody tr .total').html("Total: " + total);
    }

    function updateTable() {
        $('tbody tr').each(function (row) {
            computeRowTotal(this)
        });
        computeTotal(this)
    };
    $('select').bind('change', function () {
        computeRowTotal($(this).closest('tr'));
        computeTotal();
    });

    updateTable();

});
```